# Array of derived class stored in parent class

Tags: c++

I don't think I quite understand how to store an array of a derived class in its parent class.
I keep getting errors

> Error C3646   'list': unknown override specifier
>   Error C2065   'list': undeclared identifier

Here is the code I have

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class GameScores
{
public:
    GameEntry list[9];
    void inputList(GameEntry x);
    void sortList();
    void removeList(int r);
    void printList();
    GameScores();
};

class GameEntry :public GameScores
{
public:
    GameEntry(const string& n = "", int s = 0, const string d = "1/1/99");
    string getName() const;
    int getScore() const;
    string getDate() const;
    string setName(string n);
    int setScore(int s);
    string setDate(string d);

private:
    string name;
    int score;
    string date;
};

GameScores::GameScores()
{
    GameEntry list[9];
}

void GameScores::inputList(GameEntry x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        if (x.getScore() >= list[i].getScore())
        {
            list[i + 1] = list[i];
            list[i] = x;
        }
}

void GameScores::sortList()
{
    GameEntry swap;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10 - 1; j++)
        {
            if (list[j].getScore() > list[j].getScore() + 1)
            {
                swap = list[j];
                list[j] = list[j + 1];
                list[j + 1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
}

void GameScores::removeList(int r)
{
    for (int i = r; i < 10; i++)
    list[i - 1] = list[i];

    list[9].setScore(0);
    list[9].setName(" ");
    list[9].setDate(" ");
}

void GameScores::printList()
{
    cout << "Top Scores" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << list[i].getScore() << " " << list[i].getName() << " " << list[i].getDate() << endl;
}

GameEntry::GameEntry(const string& n, int s, const string d)    // constructor
    : name(n), score(s), date(d) { }
                                                                // accessors
string GameEntry::getName() const { return name; }
int GameEntry::getScore() const { return score; }
string GameEntry::getDate() const { return date; }

string GameEntry::setName(string n)
{
    name = n;
}

int GameEntry::setScore(int s)
{
    score = s;
}
;
string GameEntry::setDate(string d)
{
    date = d;
}

int main()
{
    GameEntry p1("John", 90, "9/9/98"), p2("Jane", 95, 8/21/98), p3("Bob", 60, "7/11/99"), p4("Jo", 92, "6/4/97");

    GameScores topScores;
    topScores.inputList(p1);
    topScores.inputList(p2);
    topScores.inputList(p3);
    topScores.inputList(p4);
    topScores.printList();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: pre-declare GameEntry

Comment: Parent classes should generally not know about child classes, plus you should consider removing the extra consecutive blank lines to reduce the scrolling.

Comment: and really, it looks like you just need to drop the inheritance and move `GameEntry` above `GameScores` (`GameScores` *has* `GameEntry`, `GameEntry` *is not* a `GameScores`).

Comment: Also, your `GameScores` constructor does not make any sense, you create a new *local* `list` array that then goes out of scope at the end of the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This design is very questionable.  What purpose is being served by making the second class inherit the first?  It looks like you'd end up with each member of the array containing an additional array with all its siblings.  Don't you want only one array?  You need to rethink this from an earlier point.

If you really have a reason for a parent class to contain an array of the child class, maybe you should define an interface (abstract base class) that both classes implement.

Answer (score 0):

To use `GameEntry` as a type in your `GameScores` class , you must forward-declare the class like so :

```
class GameEntry;

class GameScores
{
public:
    GameEntry list[9];
    void inputList(GameEntry x);
    void sortList();
    void removeList(int r);
    void printList();
    GameScores();
};
```

Comment: But you can't have a non-static member which is an array of an incomplete type.